# Windows XP Account Locked Out and Half-Deleted

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

This morning I used remote desktop to access my user account on my work machine, and everything was fine. When I came into work, Windows said my account had been locked out. I rebooted, and Windows automatically logged into the default Administrator account instead of prompting me for the password of my normal account.

I looked at User Accounts in the control panel, and I did not see my user account listed, as if it were deleted. But when I log off Administrator and try to log back in with my user account's credentials, it says my account is locked out. So it's not *quite* deleted...

Any idea what's happening? Is there a way to get it back? I would do a system restore, but system restore is turned off.

Oh, one more thing: When my computer took me to the Administrator account for the first time, there was an error saying explorer.exe had crashed.

Comment: Can you change your user's password when you're logged with local admin accnt?

Comment: No, because the account isn't listed in User Accounts.

Comment: does your normal account have admin privs, if so then its a virus.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything, you should back up your user folder. 
On windows XP, this can be found in C:\documents and settings{your user name}

Make sure that you get a backup copy of this, and you can see the files in your desktop and "my documents" folders.

If you can't get access to it, you may have to delete the user, then recreate it. 
(Files backed up (above) can be copied after you manage to log back in)

Answer (score 0):

Log in with Admin account and then:

- Right click on `My Computer` and select `Manage`.
- Click on `System Tools`.
- Click on `Local Users and Groups`.
- Select `Users`
- Select your locked account.
- Right click & select `Properties`.
- Uncheck `Account is locked out`.

[image]